# dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm issues in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

```
   fourLetterWord = @"isdjfiodjof";
   if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:fourLetterWord]) {
        self.display.text = fourLetterWord;
        return;
    }
    else
        fourLetterWord = @"";
```

This string is getting accepted.  I do not know what I am doing wrong here, but before 4.5 this worked fine.  Is this an issue with xcode 4.5, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting to the else clause instead of the if?

Comment: The string "isdjfiodjof"  is being accepted.  It answers YES when it should answer NO since that is clearly not in the english dictionary.

Comment: I'm actually running into the same problem right now. Did you ever find a solve for this? I can't get it to return false anymore, used to work fine until recently.

Comment: Is this only in iOS6?  Regardless, it sounds like a bug and should be logged with Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Haven't gotten it to work, I hoped it would be fixed with the most recent update but it has not.  Now I figure it is only an issue that apple can fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue and start working around it.[UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:fourLetterWord]) method doensn't work in the simulator for some reasons, Apple need to fix it.

BUT  if you TEST YOUR APP IN THE DEVICE [UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:fourLetterWord]) method runs and gives you the right result.

it's kinda  slow though.

hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

`dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:` always returns `YES` if no dictionary has been downloaded yet (because if there is no dictionary, it can't know whether the word is in it).

The download is automatically offered when you actually show a dictionary popover in any app. I think the download-on-demand feature was introduced in iOS 6, along with dictionaries in languages other than English.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that this works fine on my iPad running iOS 5.1.1 but returns TRUE every time on my iPod running iOS 6.1.3. I've logged it as a bug with Apple.

Update: omz is right. Once I had downloaded Apple's dictionary onto my iOS6 iPod then it validates the word correctly. It was so long ago that I installed iOS5 on my iPad I had no memory of whether I'd installed it manually or if it was done for me. Regardless, it requires a manual install on iOS6 for this method to be of use.